# Wordpress get_post_meta() - Not Return Value

Tags: wordpress

I made some meta_values under a custom post type called 'Show'.  I have confirmed that the meta values are being stored correctly in the DB.  So now, I have the following code snippet:

```
<?php
        $args = array( 'post_type' => 'show', 'posts_per_page' => 1 );
        $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
        while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
             print get_post_meta($loop->ID, 'date_meta', true);
             the_title();
        endwhile;
?>
```

The actual loop works wine, as it does display the result of the_title().  But the get_post_meta() isn't returning anything.  The key value is correct, and there is a value for it in the DB.

Also, if I try to print $loop->ID, it doesn't return anything either...

thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

needed to add a reference to the global $post variable:

```
<?php
    $args = array( 'post_type' => 'show', 'posts_per_page' => 1 );
    $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
         global $post;
         print get_post_meta($loop->ID, 'date_meta', true);
         the_title();
    endwhile;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'show', 'posts_per_page' => 1 );
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
     echo get_post_meta($loop->post_ID, 'date_meta', true);
     the_title();
endwhile;
?>
```